# Leave me crying- meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

The book is so good **it will leave me crying.**
Is this a grammatically correct way to say "I cried reading/finishing the book"?

Comment: You expect to cry **upon** finishing the book.  (**will leave** is future tense). Reviewers often say things like that, to their audiences. "This book is so good it will leave you crying."  They're recommending the book to others, who have not read it yet. They're predicting tears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is grammatical—but it doesn't mean what you said it does.

> The book is so good it will leave me crying.

When you utter that statement, it's implied that you haven't started to cry *yet*. Rather, you *will* cry at some point.

> I cried reading/finishing the book.

This sentence, on the other hand, can only have been uttered *after* the book was finished. It's not saying that you *will* cry, it's saying that you *did* cry.

The meaning of each sentence is quite different.